# How to work in a team as web developers

Tags: javascript, css

I have this web project I'm working on with a friend. However, there are problems when it comes to who should do what and when should it be done. We are using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS and we can't work on two separate computers, and ideas are always shared only when we are coding. Please help me on how or what we can use to share what to do in order to work on same project but be independent.

Comment: Just look into things like `extreme programming`, `git`, `jira` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a project management tool such as https://basecamp.com/ can help you keep track of milestones and project deadlines. Its also a good way to stay in touch with your team. There are plenty of other messaging tools you can use to share ideas within a team such as https://slack.com/

When working in a team there is always the problem of stepping on eachothers toes. You might need to edit a particular file, but someone else is working on it, or has made changes to it since you last took a copy. How do you both keep up to date with the code the other has written? Well this is where you want VC (Version Control). There are a few big names out there such as SVN, but by far the most popular is a Git (hopefully you have already heard/used it).

Install git https://git-scm.com/ and you can commit your code. You can then push your code to an online repository such as GitHub https://github.com/. Using GitHub means that you can both push your code up and pull code down to ensure you both have the changes the other has commited.

You may also find a need to track bugs and features you need to implement, when they need to be done by and who will do it. You can use tools such a Jira https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira or Visual Studio Team services (Im sure theres free alternatives that are a bit more lightweight). In essence you log tasks that need to be done on a project such as fixing a bug. Then you assign it to a person and allocate it to a sprint (sprints are a period of time you are going to work before meeting with your team and reviewing priorities and work completed, typically a sprint is 1 or 2 weeks).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At the bare minimum I would suggest that you

1. Set up a project repository with a version control system (e.g. on [GitHub](https://github.com/))
2. Use a hypervisor like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to set up independent virtual machines on the host machine. With this you can set up your own independent environments without affecting the other person's workflow.

Note: this assumes that only one person will be using the host machine at a time.